# How do I limit draggable area? it functions on top and left side, but not on the right side and bottom

Tags: javascript, java, object, overflow, draggable

So I tried to block the `draggable` contents from `overflowing` the body.

It **works** on top and on the left side.

I **can't limit** the right side and bottom.

```
            e.pageX -= e.offsetX;
            e.pageY -= e.offsetY;

            // left/right constraint
            if (e.pageX - dragoffset.x < 0) {
                offsetX = 0;
            } else if (e.pageX + dragoffset.x > document.body.clientWidth) {
                offsetX = document.body.clientWidth - e.target.clientWidth;
            } else {
                offsetX = e.pageX - dragoffset.x;
            }

            // top/bottom constraint

            if (e.pageY - dragoffset.y < 0) {
                offsetY = 0;
            } else if (e.pageY + dragoffset.y > document.body.clientHeight) {
                offsetY = document.body.clientHeight - e.target.clientHeight;
            } else {
                offsetY = e.pageY - dragoffset.y;
            }   

            el.style.top = offsetY + "px";
            el.style.left = offsetX + "px";
        }
    });
};
```

Also, my divs are getting **glitchy** while I drag them around. They only stop on the right side and bottom when the text inside them is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is drag&drop library with feature to restrict movements of draggables

https://github.com/dragee/dragee

By default it restrict movements of element inside `container`. It take into account size of element.

```js
import { Draggable } from 'dragee'
new Draggable(element, { container: document.body })
```

In same time it's possible to use custom bound function

```js
import { Draggable, BoundToRectangle, Rectangle } from 'dragee'
new Draggable(element, { 
    bound: BoundToRectangle.bounding(Rectangle.fromElement(document.body, document.body))
})
```

where `BoundToElement` describe restrictions that you need

```
class BoundToRectangle {
  constructor(rectangle) {
    this.rectangle = rectangle
  }

  bound(point, size) {
    const calcPoint = point.clone()
    const rectP2 = this.rectangle.getP3()

    if (this.rectangle.position.x > calcPoint.x) {
      (calcPoint.x = this.rectangle.position.x)
    }
    if (this.rectangle.position.y > calcPoint.y) {
      calcPoint.y = this.rectangle.position.y
    }
    if (rectP2.x < calcPoint.x + size.x) {
      calcPoint.x = rectP2.x - size.x
    }
    if (rectP2.y < calcPoint.y + size.y) {
      calcPoint.y = rectP2.y - size.y
    }

    return calcPoint
  }
}
```

Size of element you can calculate next way:

```js
let width = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(element)['width'])
let height = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(element)['height'])
```

I can also suggest to use `translate3d` property for movements instead of positions left and top, because it is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

I assume that since the draggable item is a dom element it will push the width and height of the body when moved right or down, this changes the body size, so using the body size might not be the right way. Maybe you can use `window.width` and `window.height` or so to restrict the area with values the draggable item cannot change. Hope this helps.